# Spring rest API: saveAll

Tags: spring, rest, api, save

I see in `CrudRepository` interface there is a method "`saveAll`".
There is anyway to use it without doing any customization to the code passing in a POST request an array of json of the corresponding entity?

I can't figure out why all the other methods are mapped except this.

Thanks Mik

Comment: Could you share some code?

Comment: I'd like to post from client side an array of objects to  the entity corresponding endpoint and save all object inside array. But I'd lik to know if there is any "out of the box" method without implementing Controllers. This because the CrudRepository interface automatically map basic CRUD operations. And in the interface there is a method saveAll that I don't if I can automatically use client side without implementing any code.

Comment: @Mikfaina Have you figured this one out. I'm trying to accomplish the same thing now. The client should be able to save several entities at once via an HTTP call, instead of sending several requests, one per entity.

Answer (score 0):

It will take a collection and persist. Its hard to answer your question without sample code or what you have done so far but this is how it works on some `ExampleClient` code.

Just ensure you have latest version on spring-data-jpa.

```
@Component
public class ExampleClient {

  @Autowired
  private EmployeeRepository repo;

  public void run() {
      List<Employee> employees = createEmployees();

      System.out.println(" -- saving employees --");
      System.out.println(employees);
      repo.saveAll(employees);
.......
........
```

Comment: I mean from client side is not mapped if I post an array of objects. I kow how it works server side. All methods of the interface can be used client side except this one